# Проблема с выборкой

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно выбирать данных из трех таблиц, вроде так написал код, но ошибку дает, значит, я неправильно написал, в чем проблема, подскажите?

```
(SELECT title, card FROM sistemCard LIMIT 1)
        UNION
        (SELECT numberC FROM nomberC WHERE idUser=".$myrowNU['SMI']." LIMIT 1)
        UNION
        (SELECT usr FROM tz_members WHERE id=".$myrowNU['SMI']." LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Прежде чем создавать новую тему, написав свой вопрос, пожалуйста, прочтите его сначала, и до конца, и оцените, насколько Ясно Вы изложили свою мысль для других. Неправильно заданный вопрос, или некорректный вопрос скорее всего наберет минусов в карму, и вряд-ли получит ответ, в то время, как правильно поставленный вопрос как таковой уже сам является ключом к ответу

Comment: ну как еще по другому объяснить:)

Comment: Как минимум - описать иходные данные, и что требуется получить в итоге

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
SELECT t1.title, t1.card, t2.numberC, t3.usr 
  FROM sistemCard t1, numberC t2, tz_members t3 
 WHERE t2.idUser = "$myrowNU['SMI']" 
   AND t3.id = "$myrowNU['SMI']"
```

если будет ошибка, напишите ее в комментарий.

Comment: Почти все классно) но ошибку дает:

Table 'money.numberc' doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

У вас не одинаковое количество колонок в запросах, поэтому UNION валится